# Network Traffic Emulator

Tags: networking, simulator, network-traffic

I am testing an application which monitors the traffic and identify the various hosts/machines present in the network with list of services/applications runs on them.

How will i simulate the traffic from multiple application like (Eg: Http, Https, Oracle, SQL Server, SAP etc)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any type simulator doing what you have asked.
We have load testers, load balance testers etc.

But simulating all devices and technologies like SAP etc , its really difficult.
There should be an individual application each installed on the application/device which use  network and does need ful